# I am not able to see Click Wrap option all the time from my DocuSign sandbox account

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign have recently released Click Wraps at their Momentum. I would like to take advantage of this new feature and was exploring this a little.
 Once, I was able to add a few click wrap templates using my DocuSign sandbox account but at times, I do not see them when I click on "Manage" button once I login to my DocuSign demo account.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Minal

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I suggest checking that you're logged into your DocuSign demo account (Developer Sandbox) as the administrator. Login via https://demo.docusign.net

Sometimes people login to a trial version of the DocuSign production systems by mistake (https://www.docusign.net). While Click agreements are provided in all demo accounts, they are only provided for some customer pricing plans on the production systems.

If the problem continues, you can create a demo account. Or contact DocuSign customer service.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue here and as a workaround after we logged into our demo account we were able to enter the url for the clickwraps directly to navigate to the clickwraps page.

```
https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents?view=active&type=clickwraps
```